Can you execute a block of code if a python loop is not broken
I'm looking for a more pythonic way to construct this check:
good_result = None
for item in items:
    result = process(item)
    if result.isGood():
        good_result = result
        break
if not good_result:
    deal_with_consequences_of_bad_result()

Assume that we don't want to process all items in the list, so I only want to check for the the first occurrence of a good result.

Maybe something like this:
good_result = next((result for item in items if (result := process(item)).isGood()), None)

if not good_result:
    deal_with_consequences_of_bad_result()


I'd say the for/else approach is more readable. Also if not good_result will not work well for good_result = 0.

@Jeyekomon I agree that for/else approach is more readable.
